# Area of a parallelogram - graphic

Tags: graphing-functions, area

Question:
What is the area of the parallelogram formed by the lines $y = mx, y = mx+1, y = nx, y = nx+1$?

a) $\frac{|m + n|}{(m - n)^2}$

b) $\frac{2}{|m + n|}$

c) $\frac{1}{|m + n|}$

d) $\frac{1}{|m - n|}$

I have no idea how to even approach this problem Please help?

Comment: Draw a sketch, helps most of the times.

Comment: I did draw a sketch. However, couldn't proceed further from there :/

Comment: Did you calculate the corner points?

Comment: Ummmm, not really. That will be done only in terms of m and n. Let me see.

Comment: How would I find the area of the parallelogram from the points though?

Comment: find the area of a one triangle then multiply by 2

Comment: Well obviously, but none of the triangles will be a right angle triangle. How will I find their area then? It will be a long procedure if I'm to find the area of the triangle using the points o.O

Comment: Well, if the vertices of a triangle are (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) and the area is A, then 2A = |x1(y2-y3)+x2(y3-y1)+x3(y1-y2)|

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First lets calculate all the points that form the parallelogram. Let us assume that $n\neq 0 \neq m$ The lines $y=mx$ and $y=nx$ intersect at $(0,0)$. The intersection of $y = mx+1$ and is at $(0,1)$ Then the intersection of $y=mx+1$ and $y=nx$ is at $(1/(n-m),n/(n-m)$ and because of the 'symmetry of the equations the intersection of $y=nx+1$ and $y=mx$ is at $(1/(m-n),m/(m-n))$

Here is a good answer onhow to calculate the area from the vertice points:
[Area of a parallelogram, vertices $(-1,-1), (4,1), (5,3), (10,5)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331710/area-of-a-parallelogram-vertices-1-1-4-1-5-3-10-5)