# Finding area of parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra

If these are the vertices for a parallelogram,

(0,0), (-1,3), (4,-5), (3,-2)

how do I find the area?

I know it's supposed to be a 2x2 matrix and I need to find the determinant for it but I don't know which columns of it to use. Am I supposed to draw it out?

Am I supposed to shift one of the vertices to?

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example of a parallelogram's area being evaluated in a similar fashion:-

[Area of a parallelogram, vertices $(-1,-1), (4,1), (5,3), (10,5)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331710/area-of-a-parallelogram-vertices-1-1-4-1-5-3-10-5)

After a quick glance, I'm pretty sure you can find the answer out on your own :)